# OpenLayers getFeatures() access properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers, angular-openlayers

I have some levels with many features. Each feature has properties, e.g. Values (is an Array). But I can not access this property.

When I try to access the property like that

```
layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].values
```

I get an undefined exception. I try to access it

```
layer.getSource().getFeatures().get('values')
```

Does this function not exist.

What must i do? How can i access my required values?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getProperties().values
```

or

```
layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].get('values')
```